# Does Twitter's Streaming API fetches new data everytime?

Tags: node.js, twitter, twitter-search

I am using Twitter's Streaming API in my NodeJS application. I am starting and stopping the server in my developers machine. My question is that does the API fetches new data every time? Does it return duplicate data on starting/stopping the NodeJS server?

Comment: What does Twitter API say about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every Twitter request fetches new data; however, depending on the specific request, the new data may be the same as or different from the old data.

There is nothing called "live search API." You may be referring to Twitter's Streaming API. If that's the case, then you would not receive duplicate data.

Comment: @Jones : Thanks. I have modified and corrected the name of the API. Yes I exactly wanted to confirm about "Twitter's Streaming API". Thanks a lot.